# Google reCAPTCHA in a R Shiny Application: How to?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, captcha, recaptcha

I am trying to use Google reCAPTCHA in a R `shiny` application. I managed to integrate the widget in `ui.R` :

```
tags$head(tags$script(src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js")),
tags$div(class = "g-recaptcha", id="google-captcha", 
         `data-sitekey` = "site-key: insert your own"),
```

The widget shows up and can be clicked, but now I am stuck with retrieving the response from the widget. Using `print(input$google-captcha)` in `server.R` only returns `NULL` meaning that it does not contain the required response?
Does somebody have any idea of how to access the widgets response in R `shiny`?

Comment: There are packages available on GitHub to do this. reCAPTCHA v2 - github.com/carlganz/shinyCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA v3 - github.com/sarthi2395/shinygCAPTCHAv3